# Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors. DISPLAY environment variable not set. Failed <<<<

Tags: linux, weblogic, centos7, weblogic12c

While installing weblogic server, I am getting this error. I have tried pretty much but I couldn't sort it out.

I tried by this below commands,

`# xhost +`

`yum install xorg-x11-xauth`

And I followed this steps given here. `https://superuser.com/questions/119792/how-to-use-x11-forwarding-with-putty`

I am getting this error while installing the weblogic server,

```
[oracle@minint-mkhp6g3 oracle]$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar /software/fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar
Launcher log file is /tmp/OraInstall2019-10-10_02-49-57AM/launcher2019-10-10_02-49-57AM.log.
Extracting the installer . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Done
Checking if CPU speed is above 300 MHz.   Actual 2593.996 MHz    Passed
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.  DISPLAY environment variable not set.    Failed <<<<
Checking swap space: must be greater than 512 MB.   Actual 2047 MB    Passed
Checking if this platform requires a 64-bit JVM.   Actual 64    Passed (64-bit not required)
Checking temp space: must be greater than 300 MB.   Actual 18959 MB    Passed

Some system prerequisite checks failed.
You must fulfill these requirements before continuing.

Continue? (yes [y] / no [n]) [n]
y
You have confirmed that the product can be installed on this platform.
Continuing with the installation.


Preparing to launch the Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2019-10-10_02-49-57AM
DISPLAY is not set.  Please set the DISPLAY environment variable and try again.
Depending on the Unix Shell, you can use one of the following commands as examples to set the DISPLAY environment variable:
- For csh:                      %% setenv DISPLAY 192.168.1.128:0.0
- For sh, ksh and bash:         $ DISPLAY=192.168.1.128:0.0; export DISPLAY
Use the following command to see what shell is being used:
echo $SHELL
Use the following command to view the current DISPLAY environment variable setting:
echo $DISPLAY
- Make sure that client users are authorized to connect to the X Server.
To enable client users to access the X Server, open an xterm, dtterm or xconsole as the user that started the session and type the following command:
%% xhost +
To test that the DISPLAY environment variable is set correctly, run a X11 based program that comes with the native operating system such as 'xclock':
%% <full path to xclock; see below>
If you are not able to run xclock successfully, please refer to your PC-X Server or OS vendor for further assistance.
Typical path for xclock: /usr/X11R6/bin/xclock
java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
        at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1763)
        at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1838)
        at javax.swing.JDialog.<init>(JDialog.java:272)
        at javax.swing.JDialog.<init>(JDialog.java:206)
        at javax.swing.JDialog.<init>(JDialog.java:154)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.presentation.ui.common.dialogs.SpecifyInventoryDirectoryDialog.<init>(SpecifyInventoryDirectoryDialog.java:248)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.presentation.ui.common.dialogs.SpecifyInventoryDirectoryDialog.showDialog(SpecifyInventoryDirectoryDialog.java:781)
        at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickInstaller.main(OiocOneClickInstaller.java:643)

The log(s) can be found here: /tmp/OraInstall2019-10-10_02-49-57AM.
```

I am searching solutions for this error.

Answer (score 0):

Better we can try `mobaXterm` instead of `PUTTY`.

In `mobaXterm`, Take the Xserver value and run by using the below command.

For ex,
`export DISPLAY=192.168.0.106:0.0`

Then, try this `xclock` command. You can get the clock in your screen. Once you receive the clock and then run the installation command.

Finally, webLogic server will be installed.

Comment: Still better is to use silent mode installation. It's quicker and easier.

Comment: Thanks for yout note @NaveenHiremath. But I haven't tried it earlier.. I will try this method when I do installation next time.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a minimal install to have a fresh environment and came across this message while installing WebLogic. As this is the first hit on Google, I am posting the solution here.

X11 server and related packages need to be installed.

```
yum install -y xorg-x11-server-Xorg xorg-x11-xauth xorg-x11-apps xorg-x11-utils xclock
systemctl restart sshd
```

The DISPLAY environment variable gets set with an incomplete set of RPM's which is misleading.

If you are using PuTTY, then you should also have XMing installed and running.